# How do you interpret the portfolio DV01?

Tags: fixed-income, bond, portfolio-management, dv01

I am having trouble understanding the active dv01 of a portfolio? If the active dv01 of a portfolio
is -10,000, what does that mean, all else equal? And what are different ways of increasing dv01 of a portfolio relative to its benchmark?

Comment: I thought it would be the reversed, if portfolio dv01 is positive (+10000 USD), if rates increase 1 bp, you underperform the benchmark? Failing to understand the concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Meaning of DV01**

The DV01 (Dollar Value of an 01) of a portfolio measures the change in the portfolio's value for a 1 basis point (equal to 0.01%) move in the interest rate. It's a common measure of interest rate risk in portfolios of fixed income securities.

If the active DV01 of a portfolio is -10,000, this means that for a 1 bp increase (decrease) in interest rates, the portfolio's value is expected to decrease (increase) by $10,000, ceteris paribus. This inverse relationship is due to the fact that a bond price decreases when the interest rate increases, essentially because cash flows are discounted more.

**Increasing the DV01**

To increase the DV01 of a portfolio relative to its benchmark, you can employ a number of strategies which aim to enhance the portfolio's sensitivity to interest rate movements compared to the benchmark.

The most basic one is:

- Increasing the duration of the portfolio: Buy longer-duration securities than those in the benchmark. These have higher sensitivity to interest rate changes, thereby increasing the portfolio's DV01.

Other strategies include (but are not limited to):

- Leverage: Use leverage to increase exposure to securities with a  positive DV01.
- Interest rate derivatives: Include interest rate derivatives in your portfolio to increase exposure to interest rate movements.
- Asset allocation: Shift the portfolio towards sectors with higher interest rate sensitivity (like government bonds vs short-term corporate bonds).

Comment: Thank you for the comment I also had a question about positioning>>>

If a portfolio has 5 year OAS spread of 10bps and 10year OAS spread of 5bps. Is that what we "Credit Steepener"?

And if the Index 5-year and 10-year OAS steepens from 55 to 56, so move of 1bp. Did the portfolio  out outperform the Index just based on credit?